# Creating a hyperlink in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a hyper link in python that includes string and variables but i keep getting a syntax error, I think its probably because of quotations but I cant seen to figure it out. Thanks for the help.

```
'<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:'str(p['latitude']+'+'+str(p['longitude']))'">Click Here</a>'})
```

Comment: You are missing `+` twice. Please proofread your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both Latitude and Longitude are Integers:

```
'<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:'+str(p['latitude'])+'+'+str(p['longitude'])+'">Click Here</a>'
```

Try This.

Your mistake is that you are not concatenating the strings properly.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thanks alot.